# React material-ui "select" component display bug

Tags: reactjs, drop-down-menu, material-ui, form-control

I experience a strange problem with my select from material-ui core 1.2.1.
The Header of the Select is going back into the selected value after I click somewhere else:

[image]
[image]

Here is my code of the Select + FormControl:

```
this.state = {
        selectedReseller: '',
        resellers: []
    };

{this.state.isAdmin && this.state.resellers.length > 0 ?
                        <span className="license-top-controls">
                        <FormControl className="license-top-controls select">
                            <InputLabel htmlFor="selectedReseller">Partner</InputLabel>
                            <Select
                                value={this.state.selectedReseller}
                                onChange={this.handleResellerChange('selectedReseller')}
                                inputProps={{
                                    name: 'selectedReseller',
                                    id: 'selectedReseller'
                                }}>
                                <MenuItem value="alle">Alle</MenuItem>
                                {
                                    this.state.resellers.map(reseller => {
                                        return <MenuItem key={reseller.id}
                                                         value={reseller.id}>{reseller.name}</MenuItem>
                                    })
                                }
                            </Select>
                        </FormControl>
                            </span>
                        : null}
```

Maybe someone of you has experiences a similar issue.

Comment: Which version of material-ui are you using?

Comment: material-ui core 1.2.1

Comment: Have you tried updating to v3.x? I can't reproduce the bug with the newest version of material-ui. Sidenote: You should not wrap the components in a `<span>` element, as some of the components translate to `<div>`s, which is not allowed by the HTML specification. Just replace the `<span>` element with a `<div>` component.

Comment: Thanks for your help! I updated to 3.3.1 and it fixed the problem. Had to do some rework of my other styling but thats ok :)